# Increase speed of MySQL LIKE query?

Tags: mysql, performance, search

For an airport input field with autocompletion, there currently is one table with airport descriptions, `autocomplete_airport`:

```
lang | description (with INDEX)                           | ...
-----+----------------------------------------------------+----
pt   | New York - John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos    | ...
pt   | Nova Iorque - John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos | ...
...
```

Autocompletion works on individual words. So when the user enters "yor", then "new york" shows up (if in LIMIT). The query currently works as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM autocomplete_airport WHERE lang = "pt"
AND (description LIKE "%(yor)%"
     OR description LIKE "yor%"
     OR description LIKE "% yor%")
ORDER BY description
LIMIT 15
```

Now I wonder how to speed up things. One idea is to create the following database structure, with tables `autocomplete_airport` and `autocomplete_airport_word`:

```
id   | lang | description (with INDEX)                           | ...
-----+------+----------------------------------------------------+----
123  | pt   | New York - John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos    | ...
124  | pt   | Nova Iorque - John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos | ...
...

word (with INDEX) | autocomplete_airport_id
------------------+------------------------
New               |                     123
York              |                     123
John              |                     123
F                 |                     123
Kennedy           |                     123
JFK               |                     123
...
```

Then SELECT would only need to search at the beginning of strings:

```
SELECT DISTINCT autocomplete_airport.*
FROM autocomplete_airport
INNER JOIN autocomplete_airport_word 
ON autocomplete_airport.id = autocomplete_airport_word.autocomplete_airport_id
WHERE lang = "pt"
AND word LIKE "yor%"
ORDER BY description
LIMIT 15
```

Is that new structure worth the trouble? Would it really speed up things? Is there a simpler way?

## Update

Just noticed that the *word table* has a flaw. The consequence: Searching for "New York" would not give any result. What should work:

```
term (with INDEX)                               | autocomplete_airport_id
------------------------------------------------+------------------------
New York - John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos | 123
York - John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos     | 123
John F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos            | 123
F Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos                 | 123
Kennedy (JFK), Estados Unidos                   | 123
(JFK), Estados Unidos                           | 123
Estados Unidos                                  | 123
Unidos                                          | 123
JFK                                             | 123
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As MartinK says, if your table has just a few hundred rows, your query should be pretty quick even without optimization - it's worth checking what's going on.

However, the best way to search text fields is to use full text indexing (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) - this is designed for exactly the case you're describing.

Comment: I was not sure about mysql fulltext index capabilities. However, 'Boolean Full-Text Searches' (and the * wildcard) do indeed look useful for this problem. I was a bit afraid that 'stopwords' and 'stemming' (not enabled by default) could produce somewhat unexpected results for a user. YMMV. Anyway, upvoted :)

Comment: Looks like the best solution. Haven't applied it yet, though, since I first need approval from my client. Adding the index is not so easy in this case as the whole DB is InnoDB (for good reason), and functionality for changing a single table to MyISAM is not provided in the system. Still, I have thought about a way to work around this problem.

Comment: If I understand correctly FULLTEXT cannot use wildcards so it's useless in my case

Comment: @MartinZvarík - it would help if you defined your case, but fulltext search doesn't really have the concept of "wildcards" - but it does support searching for _querystring_ in target column regardless of the position of that _querystring_. See https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-natural-language-search.aspx for an example.

Comment: @NevilleKuyt I have random characters like "SS2352" and using FULLTEXT as '\*23\*' didn't find anything ‍♂️ ... so I kept using LIKE

Comment: It's probably best to ask a new question with your specific case - but FULLTEXT doesn't use wildcards, if you search for just '23' it _should_ work.

Answer (score 4):

Your proposed approach may speed up your query. The important thing about LIKE queries is that the wildcard % must not be at the start of the pattern.

`LIKE '%foobar'` cannot make use of an index.
`LIKE 'foobar%'` can make use of an index.

However if you *just* have a few hundreds airports to store I'd think twice if a full table scan really hurts that much.

Use `EXPLAIN select {rest of query}` to find out how and if the DB is using an.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html
(Scroll down to *B-Tree Index Characteristics*, this is the default mysql index type)

Comment: Good to know that `LIKE '%foobar'` cannot make use of an index. Indeed this is what `EXPLAIN select {rest of query}` shows. Now I am thinking whether do use fulltext search or the separate *word table* that I originally proposed. By the way, there are around 10,000 entries per `lang`. Should do some profiling...

Comment: Solving it by 'just' adding an index and modifying your query a bit sounds terribly tempting. I believe the data in the airport table is constant so a MyIsam table is fine here to (you could still do 'LOCK TABLE' from time to time :). I'd give it a shot.  Good luck