# MySQL Searching with indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently discovered how to benefit from the information EXPLAIN provides for SQL and I figured I should run all my queries through an EXPLAIN clause to see if I have unoptimized stuff. Turns out I have and I don't know what to do about it..

If I EXPLAIN this query

```
SELECT `id`,`username`,`first_name`,`last_name` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE (`username` LIKE '%kelon%' 
  OR `email` LIKE '%kelon%' 
  OR `first_name` LIKE '%kelon%' 
  OR `last_name` LIKE '%kelon%' 
  OR `facebook` LIKE '%kelon%' 
  OR `twitter` LIKE '%kelon%' 
  OR `skype` LIKE '%kelon%')
```

I get `ALL` for `type`, which is obviously the worst scenario, and I get `NULL` for `possible_keys` even though I have indexes on all of the columns. How can I optimize this messy query so that mysql wouldn't run away in case of a few million records?

Comment: [mysql like performance boost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481528/mysql-like-performance-boost), [Increase speed of MySQL LIKE query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717190/increase-speed-of-mysql-like-query)

Comment: @Uours well I can't have a constant prefix because that's data inputted from the user that I'm searching upon and I can't have fulltext searches because InnoDB doesn't support fulltext. Does that mean that there's nothing that could be done?

Comment: [Fulltext Search with InnoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381186/fulltext-search-with-innodb)

Comment: @Uours unfortunately my hosting provider supports version 5.5.something `QQ`

Comment: This is never going to perform well when using `LIKE` searches. See my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the answer could be to have FULLTEXT indexes .

But considering your table is currently InnoDB and that your hosting provider currently supports MySQL version 5.5 , I can only think of these options :

- Switch that table to MyISAM
- See if external full text search engine is an option : [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) , [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) , [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) etc.
- Change to hosting provider that supports MySQL 5.6.4 or higher
- Wait for your hosting provider to upgrade MySQL to 5.6.4 or higher

You can also try this to see if it makes any difference in good way :

```
SELECT `id`,`username`,`first_name`,`last_name` 
FROM `users` 
WHERE (
        `username` LIKE 'kelon%' 
    OR  `email` LIKE 'kelon%' 
    OR  `first_name` LIKE 'kelon%' 
    OR  `last_name` LIKE 'kelon%' 
    OR  `facebook` LIKE 'kelon%' 
    OR  `twitter` LIKE 'kelon%' 
    OR  `skype` LIKE 'kelon%'

    OR  `username` LIKE '%kelon%' 
    OR  `email` LIKE '%kelon%' 
    OR  `first_name` LIKE '%kelon%' 
    OR  `last_name` LIKE '%kelon%' 
    OR  `facebook` LIKE '%kelon%' 
    OR  `twitter` LIKE '%kelon%' 
    OR  `skype` LIKE '%kelon%'
)
```

Links :
[What to do with MySQL Full Text Search while migrating to Innodb ?](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/10/what-to-do-with-mysql-full-text-search-while-migrating-to-innodb/)
[What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam)